Cygwin's git ssh problem - no matching host key type found
After updating cygwin packages the cygwin's git is no longer able to access the repository.
Everything was working perfectly before the update.
$ git pull
Unable to negotiate with xxx.xxx.xxx.xx port 7999: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.


There are multiple similar questions on the Internet and basically everyone suggests the same solution which is adding
  HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
  PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa

to  ~/.ssh/config
or setting GIT_SSH_COMMAND in a similar way.
I tried that and it did not work for me.
Things to note:

My git for windows which is using putty and the same key is working just fine with that repository.
I understand I can call git for windows from cygwin but I want to understand why cygwin's git is not working


The key is added to the ssh agent:
$ ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:fingerprint /cygdrive/f/cygwin/username/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)




ssh-rsa is among supported keys:
$ ssh -Q key
ssh-ed25519
ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com
sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com
sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com
sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com
sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com
ssh-rsa
ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com




ssh version:
ssh -v localhost
OpenSSH_9.8p1, OpenSSL 3.0.15 3 Sep 2024

Debug output when directly connecting with ssh to git's host:port
$ ssh -vv xxx.xx.xx.xxx -p 7999
OpenSSH_9.8p1, OpenSSL 3.0.15 3 Sep 2024
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname xxx.xx.xx.xxx is address
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xx.xx.xxx [xxx.xx.xx.xxx] port 7999.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/f/cygwin/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/f/cygwin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/f/cygwin/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/f/cygwin/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/f/cygwin/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/f/cygwin/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/f/cygwin/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/f/cygwin/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/f/cygwin/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/f/cygwin/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/f/cygwin/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/f/cygwin/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version SSHD-UNKNOWN
debug1: compat_banner: no match: SSHD-UNKNOWN
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to xxx.xx.xx.xxx:7999 as 'username'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /cygdrive/f/cygwin/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c,kex-strict-c-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: (no match)
Unable to negotiate with xxx.xx.xx.xxx port 7999: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa


what is the debug output of directly invoked ssh command to that host&port, the parts relating to hostkeys, when you try adding a bunch of -v flags?

Output is too long to put in a comment, edited original question and added it to the bottom
